# QItemDelegate with custom widgets

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qitemdelegate

I'm having problems with my `QTableView` and `QItemDelegate` classes. For one column my delegate creates a simple combo box and everything works just fine. For my 2nd column I need a widget that has two combo boxes in a single widget.

I've written the following code in my `QItemDelegate`, just to be clear this only shows code for my 2nd column, the one that doesn't work. The other simple Combo-box isn't shown as it works fine:

```
QWidget *UserDefinedUnitsDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent,const QStyleOptionViewItem & option ,const QModelIndex & index ) const
{
    //set up a simple widget with a layout
    QWidget* pWidget = new QWidget(parent);
    QHBoxLayout* hLayout = new QHBoxLayout(pWidget);
    pWidget->setLayout(hLayout);

    //add two combo boxes to the layout
    QComboBox* comboEditor = new QComboBox(pWidget);    
    QComboBox* comboEditor2 = new QComboBox(pWidget);   

    //now add both editors to this
    hLayout->addWidget(comboEditor);
    hLayout->addWidget(comboEditor2);
    return pWidget;
}
```

Now this displays just fine but when I edit it and click elsewhere it doesn't stop editing. Can anyone offer any pointers?

Edit: So i need to call CommitData() and closeEditor() at some point. Can anyone offer pointers on where to call these?

Thanks.

Comment: How your questions is related to `QItemDelegate`? Show some code.

Comment: updated to show that this code is within a QItemDelegate::createEditor method. Thanks for pointing it out, it wasn't very clear.

Comment: Where do you call `QAbstractItemView::closeEditor` / `commitData`?

Comment: I've not set that up as when I used a simple ComboBox it appears to do that itself.

Comment: Yes. But you are using your custom editor.

Comment: I see. So i need to close and commit data. Where would be best to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the editor widget as a member of class and emit commitData when the current index of one of the comboboxes has changed. So you can connect currentIndexChanged(int) to a slot and emit commitData from there:

```
QWidget *UserDefinedUnitsDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent,const QStyleOptionViewItem & option ,const QModelIndex & index ) const
{
    //set up a simple widget with a layout
    pWidget = new QWidget(parent);
    QHBoxLayout* hLayout = new QHBoxLayout(pWidget);
    pWidget->setLayout(hLayout);

    //add two combo boxes to the layout
    QComboBox* comboEditor = new QComboBox(pWidget);    
    QComboBox* comboEditor2 = new QComboBox(pWidget);   

    connect(comboEditor,SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),this,SLOT(setData(int)));
    connect(comboEditor2,SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),this,SLOT(setData(int)));

    //now add both editors to this
    hLayout->addWidget(comboEditor);
    hLayout->addWidget(comboEditor2);
    return pWidget;
}

void UserDefinedUnitsDelegate::setData(int val)
{
    emit commitData(pWidget);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it would work but ideally it wouldn't set the data 'til you've finished (possibly) editing both comboboxes. All I can think is to check for clicking elsewhere in the view.